# How to flush the APC cache in Prestashop

Tags: caching, prestashop, apc, prestashop-1.6

In the backoffice of Prestashop, there is no option to flush the cache (*Advanced parameters - Performance*), it is only possible to disable the cache.

Different types of cache and how to flush them

- Smarty compile cache: Delete the subfolders under `cache/smarty/compile`
- Smarty template cache: Delete the subfolders under `cache/smarty/cache`
- Cache using Filesystem: Delete the subfolders under `cache/cachefs`

But how can I go about flushing the cache if I use APC Cache ?

A subsidiary question: Is it possible to set a global ttl ? By default, everything gets cached forever.

Comment: i don't know which version of prestashop are you using, but on my 1.6.0.9 under Advanced parameters -> Performance there's a "Clear Cache" button on the top green toolbar (this will flush your smarty/xml/js/css cache). For the APC/Xcache system prestashop can't do much since they depend on their relative .ini files and must be manually configured eg. http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/php-apc-configuration-and-usage-tips-and-tricks/ .

Comment: Yes, unluckily Prestashop have no control over the general/db cache, as APC settings (and any other caching system) are bound to the server, not the prestashop installation. To change those setting you have to modify the .ini file, eg. the apc.ini. There are some guide around that tell you how to set up TTL/dimesios/chunck and so on. I can't help you much here since i'm not an expert on the APC system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To flush the APC user cache, you have to install the administration interface for APC (apc.php). This file is bundled with the download for APC. Just copy it to a folder that is accessible from the web, the edit it to set a password.
After that, you can connect and flush the cache when needed. It is possible to flush the system cache and the user cache separately.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple php function: add all cache dirs to array and check it:

```
foreach ($cacheDirs as $dir)
            if (file_exists($dir))
                    $this->emptydir($dir);
```

Other way, use a free module to clean it: http://www.prestatoolbox.com/free-prestashop-modules/122-clear-the-cache-of-prestashop.html

Comment: My question is about APC Cache, not filesystem cache.

Comment: @elPresta nice answer, but you should expand on it a bit to make it usable (provide cacheDirs values). A lot of people like me land on this page searching for a general solution that you provided. Modules won't work as sometimes you need to clear cache to even access the site (for example, after changing environments)

Comment: @bg17aw Look at my question. I already enumerate the cache dirs that one needs to empty.